# how to implement 'one time password' in php/javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implement one time password in registration page of a website. user enters his mobile no and presses 'Generate OTP' button. Page ***DOES NOT*** changes. he receives OTP via SMS. he enters the OTP in the homepage and presese the 'submit' button. now the OTP is matched and if found good, registration request is entered in the database table.

I am clueless how to keep the page 'unchanged' while pressing the 'Generate OTP' button. I have implemented the same functionality but in two pages. here  I need to implement it in one page only. Any help?

Comment: Without a doubt **impossible** in pure HTML. You'll need AT LEAST Javascript/AJAX and/or a server-side endpoint as well. The title of your question indicates you want an HTML solution, but you've tagged this Javascript and jQuery: **please clarify**.

Comment: Maybe you can get away without javascript... what if you use the 'target' attribute for a form to POST the Mobile Number to an iFrame in the same page, which handles the OTP generation code.  Then you can use a normal form for entering the OTP and submitting the registration.

Comment: `$("#parent").on("click", "#theSubmitButton", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` - by passing the `e` paramater (which can be anything) you can prevent the default action of the submit button which naturally is to execute the form action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1:** This is possible without using javascript, if you use an iFrame.

In the form that requests the mobile number, just add a `"target='name_of_your_iFrame'"` attribute.  The action of that form should be the script that generates and sends the OTP to the user.

Below this form on the same page, a normal form can be used by user to input his OTP and to register.

Style the iFrame so that it is a hidden element on your HTML page, or you could use it for providing feedback to the user that his OTP was sent or not.

**OPTION 2:** Otherwise, using jQuery AJAX is another option, something like this maybe:

```
var otp_url = 'otp.php';
$('form[name=form_mobile_nr]').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mobile_nr = $('input:text[name=mobile_nr]').val();
    $.post(otp_url, {mobile_nr:mobile_nr}, function(response) {
        if (response) alert(response);
    });
});
```

In your php script ('otp.php') you can get and use the mobile nr:

```
$mobile_nr = !empty($_POST["mobile_nr"]) ? $_POST["mobile_nr"] : NULL;
if ($mobile_nr) {
    // test if valid number
    // generate OTP
    // create database entry for mobile_nr and OTP
    // send OTP to user
}
else echo "Please supply a valid mobile number.";
```